# how can i assign MessageEvents' message to string variable in dart/flutter/redis

Tags: flutter, dart, redis, stream, event-handling

i am using [dartis 0.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/dartis) for my redis connection and copied the code from pubsub example folder,here it is;

```
void main() async {
runApp(MyApp());


final broker =
  await redis.PubSub.connect<String, String>('redis://localhost:6379');
 print('connected');
 
ProcessSignal.sigint.watch().listen((_) async {
await broker.disconnect();
exit(0);});
    
 // Outputs the data received from the server.
  broker.stream.listen(print,onError: print,onDone: () => exit(0));

  broker.psubscribe(pattern: 'commands');
}
```

and this my terminal message;

I/flutter (26344): connected

I/flutter (26344): SubscriptionEvent: {command=psubscribe, channel=commands, channelCount=1}

I/flutter (26344): MessageEvent<String, String>: {channel=commands, message=7, pattern=commands}

the code works but i need to get MessageEvent' message and assign it to string variable,im probably couple lines of code far but couldnt succeeded yet.Further more, its inside of main' body during now for testing and stuff but it'll be in one of the stateful widget in the project so im thinking to write a function with returning to string,then i'll be able to use it somewhere else so yeah i hope i made it clear,if you guys can help me to figure this out,i would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
broker.stream.listen((event){
  if(event is MessageEvent){

    print(event.message);
    if(event.message == '7'){
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Majors()));



    }
  }else{
    print(event);
  }
},onError: print,onDone: () => exit(0));
```

it was super easy  :) like, i mentioned in the questions just im super new to ascyn programming, here is the answer,i hope it would be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument to broker.stream.listen is where each event is sent, in this case "print" which is dutifully printing out to the terminal. Change that to your own method call to handle the event:

```
broker.stream.listen(callYourMethodHere, onError: print, onDone: () => exit(0));
```

Comment: broker.stream.listen((event){
      if(event is MessageEvent){

        print(event.message);
        if(event.message == '7'){
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Majors()));



        }
      }else{
        print(event);
      }
    },onError: print,onDone: () => exit(0));   im doing voice controlled kiosk and the navigation through app will be voice commands so i needed the message but it was outputed as list but i made it,thank you for quick reply